# How can I add/remove a listener to notifications to a category on UIApplication

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've added a category to UIApplication and I'd like to make it listen for notifications.

If it were my class I could do this in the init/dealloc. But as its a category of a built in class what is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the shared UIApplication from anywhere in your app with `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` so if you want to make it listen for notifications you can do it in the usual way in (say) the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of your application's delegate:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:[UIApplication sharedApplication] selector:@selector(yourCategoryMethod:) name:@"WhateverNotificationName" object:WhateverObject];
```

(You can also use the application that's passed as an argument to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` instead of `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` if you do the notification setup here.  The two objects will certainly be the same.)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Create a method to act on Notification Event

```
-(void)myObserver
{
    // some action here
}
```

Step 2: Create an Observer in your viewDidLoad Method and Register it with your ViewController Class to get Notification of some action

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myObserver) name:@"YourObserverKey" object:nil];
```

Step 3: Post/Fire Notification, So all the Listners can get Notified

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"YourObserverKey" object:nil];
```

Step 4 : Never miss it, Remove Your Observer As you Leave the ViewController, otherwise it may lead to application crash.usually in viewDidUnLoad method.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"YourObserverKey"];
```